# CSS bug AskDifferent: add comment

Tags: bug, design

This CSS piece is messing up and causing a weird behaviour when you get close with your mouse to the "Add Comment" Button.

This applies to both, Meta and AskDifferent.

```
a.comments-link:hover {
padding: 0px 3px 2px 3px;
```

This piece of CSS is also related to the issue:

```
.comments-link {
padding: 0px 3px 2px 3px;
color: #888;
font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
display: inline-block;
padding: 2px 7px 3px 8px; <--
```

Can anyone poke for a fix please? ([Jin?](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/users/6/jin))

See this image for the place and button I mean:
[image: See this image for the place and button I mean:]

Comment: Does kit show the page as this [bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/219799/adding-a-comment-hides-parts-of-earlier-comments)

Comment: That's not even close to what I meant, I've added a picture with the button I mean. The text is in Dutch, but irrelevant for this question. Put your mouse on that location and it will start to bling around.